# Integration of CosmosDB with Azure fuction and SignalR

Tags: function, signalr, azure-cosmosdb

i am working on the sample example provided by microsoft in the link below
https://anthonychu.ca/post/cosmosdb-real-time-azure-functions-signalr-service/
I have followed all the steps by i am getting the error below while running the code with azure function locally:

> The listener for function 'Functions.OnDocumentsChanged' was unable to
>   start. [2/18/2019 9:50:54 PM] The listener for function
>   'Functions.OnDocumentsChanged' was unable to start.
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ChangeFeedProcessor: The lease collection,
>   if partitioned, must have partition key equal to id

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is quite clear, the Trigger uses a secondary (Leases) collection to store the state. On your Trigger definition you can specify, on the [Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#trigger---configuration) if you want to specify a particular Leases collection name / database name or leave the default ("leases"). 
The Trigger can also create the Leases collection for you if it does not exist through the `CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists` attribute.

In your case, you seem to already have the leases collection previously created.

The problem is that the leases collection, if it's partitioned, it needs to be by the `/id` that is what the error message is saying:

> The lease collection, if partitioned, must have partition key equal to
>   id

So to fix this scenario you can either:

1. Delete your current leases collection and use `CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true` to let the Trigger create it for you.
2. Manually create your leases collection and set `/id` as the Partition Key.

Comment: Hi Matias Thanks for the response,i deleted the leases collection and added the line u mentioned,but now when i run the code is stuck at [2/20/2019 3:07:35 AM] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000001E2F93C0'.

Comment: That means that the Function was initialized. Are you making changes in the Cosmos DB collection to trigger the Function?